# How do you Select the Top record from a Group of Rows from a Table in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am `SELECT`ing a group of records but one column yields distinct values in two or more results. I just want to `SELECT` the top value; not the `Min` one or the `Max` value, but the `Top N` value encountered by SQL Server 2008. Is there any aggregation mechanism that will perform this?

**E.g.**

Table has:

`Microsoft MSFT 12/21/05
Microsoft MSFT 10/22/05
Microsoft MSFT 11/23/06
Paramount PMNT 02/21/05
Paramount PMNT 01/23/06`



I execute:
SELECT   [Name], [Symbol], PriceDate
FROM     aaa
GROUP BY [Name], [Symbol]

The desired result is:

`Microsoft MSFT 12/21/05

Paramount PMNT 02/21/05`

(`TOP` fails)

Comment: "TOP" is meaningless without an ORDER BY.

Comment: SQL Server does not store rows in any particular order (well, Clustered Indexes do!) and are entirely subject to change at SQL Server's whim. It seems that you do, in fact, want the Min(PriceDate) function but are explicitly denying it in the question. Otherwise, you're giving yourself meaningless results.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I think all the answers do NOT answer the question (but of course maybe I got the question wrong):

If you do not group, you might e.g. get MSFT twice
so we start with something like this

```
select name, symbol, x(date)
from sometable 
group by name, symbol
```

The question as I get it is concerned with the function x() which is to return the first element of the date column in the respective group. The problem is: there is no natural order of rows in a relational database. So such a function can't exist, since it is not defined.

You need another column defining the order, e.g. the column timestamp:

```
select 
    a.name, 
    a.symbol, 
    (
        select b.date 
        from sometable 
        where b.timestamp = min(a.timestamp) 
        and a.name = b.name
        and a.symbol = b.symbol
    ) as first_date
from sometable as a
group by name, symbol
```

This at least works in oracle. If sqlserver doesn't like this one can rewrite it as a join.
The alternative would be analytic functions which I was told are supported by sqlserver

Comment: They don't answer because all answers (when I post this) come before the rewrite of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1   [Name], [Symbol], PriceDate
FROM     aaa
GROUP BY [Name], [Symbol]
```

Comment: doas this work in sql server? Wouldn't it complain about pricedate being not a group by column nor an aggregate function?

Answer (score 0):

`Select TOP` doesn't make sense if you don't specify the order (with `ORDER BY` smt), so you wanna do smt like:

```
SELECT TOP N *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY anyFields
```

You'll possibly get inconsistent results (there's nothing assuring the opposite) without order by.

Answer (score 0):

one way, you can also use a variable instead of 1 since sql server 2005

```
select top (1) * 
from SomeTable
order by SomeColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT [Name], [Symbol], PriceDate

FROM   aaa

WHERE  PriceDate =

(

   SELECT Top 1 aaa_2.PriceDate FROM aaa aaa_2
 
    WHERE aaa_2.[Name]   = aaa.[Name]

      AND aaa_2.[Symbol] = aaa.[Symbol]

)`